# Emulating Pass by reference using pointers in C

Tags: c

This C program is suppose to get five integer values from the user and stores them in an array. Second, it will ask for another integer n from the user. This value will serve as a multiplier to the elements of the array. Next, it will modify the elements of the array such that the new value is n times the original value, where n is the multiplier. I'm to use a **function** passing the address of the **first array element, and n,** to modify the values.

Now this is the code I came up with, but it only modifies the first element of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

void multiply(int *aPtr, int);

int main(){
    int array[SIZE];
    int i=0;
    int m;

    printf("Enter 5 integers: ");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        }

    printf("Please enter the multiplier: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    multiply(&array[0], m);

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        printf("%d  ", array[i]);
        }

    return 0;
    }

void multiply(int *aPtr, int mul){

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    *aPtr = *(aPtr+i) * mul;

    }
```

Comment: Q: why do you pass `i` to `multiply()`. that can be local.

Comment: Q: why not `multiply(array, m);`?

Comment: Q: what do you think `*aPtr = *(aPtr+i) * mul;` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiplication you are storing all values to the same location,i.e, `*ptr`. Change

```
*aPtr = *(aPtr+i) * mul;
```

to

```
*(aPtr+i) = *(aPtr+i) * mul;
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
*aPtr = *(aPtr+i) * mul;
```

to

```
*(aPtr+i) = *(aPtr+i) * mul;
```

Also note in C there is no pass-by-reference. Arguments are copied by value. You might *simulate* it but its not an *emulation*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment the array position. Make your code like this. While calling you have to pass the array address.    `multiply(array, m);`

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++,aPtr++)
*aPtr = *aPtr * mul;
```

Or else.

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
*(aPtr+i) = *(aPtr+i) * mul;
```

Because *aPtr is pointing to the first position of the array. After the first multiplication  we have to move to second position. So the incrementation needs. Sorry for the first answer.

Comment: Have you tested? `*aPtr = *(aPtr+i) * mul;` should be `*aPtr = *(aPtr) * mul;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to multiply the values in the each position and store it in the same position again.
In your code the last value which was multiplied will only be stored, because `*aPtr` will be pointing to the first position.
Try this code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

void multiply(int *aPtr, int);

int main(){
    int array[SIZE];
    int i=0;
    int m;

    printf("Enter 5 integers: ");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("Please enter the multiplier: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    multiply(&array[0], m);

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
            printf("%d  ", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void multiply(int *aPtr, int mul){
   int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
            *(aPtr + i) = *(aPtr+i) * mul;

}
```